Не могу добавить Lubuntu в Grub2Win
Я хотел сделать себе Dual Boot при помощи Grub2Win (Ранее не делал Dual Boot), но у меня нету флешки, на которую я могу записать Iso файл Lubuntu. У меня есть только Iso файл Lubuntu, нету никаких флешек и т.п., я пытался редактировать файл grub.cfg ничего не вышло, он возвращался в исходное состояние, так же я пытался через интерфейс программы сделать это, но увы не вышло. Спрашивал советов ChatGPT, нормальных советов не получил, помогите пожалуйста.

Как вы планировали установку ОС без внешнего носителя?

т.е. у вас установлен дистрибутив ubuntu, но вы хотите его же (набор пакетов того же дистрибутива под условным именем lubuntu) установить ещё раз? а зачем? вам нужна de, которая запускается в lubuntu? так установите пакет и загружайте.

@aleksandrbarakin У меня Windows 11

у меня нету флешки - cd/dvd или запасной винчестер есть?

@aleksandrbarakin Нету
